# How to store model class in MVC into a LocalStorage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, local-storage

I have a employee class inside Model. Now I need to store the properties inside the employee class into a LocalStorage. How to perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize the Object (e.g. to XML or JSON) and store the resulting sting.

To Load it, deserialize the string again.

Comment: LocalStorage is not a reference to the harddrive. It is a [HTML5 feature](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You can store stuff either in a cookie or in the localstorage.